# Python string format with incorrect values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that I'd like to format but the values I'm using to format may or may not be proper values (`None`, or `''`). In any event that one of these improper values is passed, I still want the string to format, but ignoring any values that will not work. For example:

```
mystring = "{:02d}:{:02d}"
mystring.format('', 1)
```

In this case I'd like my output to be `:01`, thus negating the fact that `''` won't work for the first value in the string. I looked at something like

```
class Default(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key): 
        return key.join("{}")

d = Default({"foo": "name"})

print("My {foo} is {bar}".format_map(d)) # "My name is {bar}"
```

But as I'm *not* using a dictionary for values, I don't think this solution will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own formatter and override [`format_field()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format_field) to catch these errors and just returns empty strings. Here's the basics (you might want to edit to only catch certain errors):

```
import string

class myFormat(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        try:
            return super().format_field(value, format_spec)
        except ValueError:
            return ''

fmt = myFormat()
mystring = "{:02d}:{:02d}"

print(fmt.format(mystring, *(2, 1)))
# 02:01

print(fmt.format(mystring, *('', 1)))
# :01
```

Comment: Is there any way to incorporate a value other than `''` in the `return` statement? An optional parameter, for example. If I wanted to return `missing:01`, for example, instead of a blank string?

Comment: @AGH_TORN if you `return 'missing'` in the `except` block you *will* get `missing:01`. If that not working for you?

Comment: I thought it would but it is not working. I added an optional parameter in the `format_field` function that is returned in the return statement, however, it seems like it's just skipping over it. I still get `:01` returned.

Comment: I should specify, I added the optional parameter to the function and the return statement is returning that parameter. That's the portion that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try-except to check if each value is valid:

```
out = []
for v in ['', 1]:
    # Check if v can be converted to a decimal number
    try:
        out.append(format(v, '02d'))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        out.append('')

print(':'.join(out))  # -> :01
```